# How to define displaytag.tld offline?

Tags: struts2, pagination, displaytag, tld

I want to define my `displaytag.tld` offline so that my application will no longer need to access `uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"`, i put

```
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="/displaytag"%>
```

in my jsp but it has error, i put my `displaytag-1.2.jar` inside `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`. Can anyone advise me what to do next in order to eliminate the error? I'm using Eclipse IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" Look like a URL to a web resource.but it is not. it just a name that happens to be formatted as a URL. so instance of 
`<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="/displaytag"%>`    use
`<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>`
you can see  tld file in inside META-INF folder of your jar file.